# How to portably exit the current Lisp process with a given error code in Common Lisp?

Tags: operating-system, common-lisp

I want to call a function that would end the current Lisp process with a specific exit code.

In python, I would write this: `os.exit(15)`

How would I do this portably in Common Lisp?

("bordeaux-threads"-like portability is fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`quit`](https://asdf.common-lisp.dev/uiop.html#index-quit) from [uiop](https://asdf.common-lisp.dev/uiop.html) (Which is bundled with every commonly used common lisp implementation):

```lisp
(require :uiop) ; Or if using QuickLisp, (ql:quickload :uiop)
(uiop:quit 0) ; normal exit
(uiop:quit 15) ; error status 15
```

Comment: but here quickload not needed? It's already there in ASDF and the implementation. `require` could be needed, not on my machine© but I had the need on CI.

Comment: Not needed but if you're already using QL for other stuff might as well use it for uiop too for consistency.